# Detect class name of method by name of extended class and method using php?

Tags: php, class, object

I want to know where is method of class in PHP. I define `Animal` class and `run` method. I define `Dog` class extends `Animal` class.

```
$dog = new Dog();
echo where_is_method($dog->run); // -> Animal:run
```

I want to get output from `where_is_method` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`ReflectionMethod`](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getmethod.php) class to find class name of method.

```
class Animal {
    function run() {
        return 'run';
    }
}
class Dog extends Animal {
    function other(){}
}
$dog = new Dog();
```

```
$reflection = new ReflectionMethod($dog, 'run');
$className = $reflection->class;
// Animal
```

Check result in [demo](https://3v4l.org/YeOVa)